# Selenium(PYTHON) Click only works sometimes

Tags: python, selenium, click, webautomation

So i noticed that i have a heavy program that i run, and certain variables that i declare dont always click, but sometimes they do, however when they dont, it doesnt give me an error that the object has no attribute 'click'. which is weird because if i manually go to the element, and click, it works no problem. what i wanna know is how can i write a program to ensure that whatever i wanna click meets a condition of some sort to click the element no problem, because it sometimes works, and sometimes doesnt

```
x = 2 # an index of some sort

desiredItem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='trades-container']/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul").find_elements_by_class_name("item-card-thumb-container")[x]
desiredItem.click()
```

what you see only sometimes clicks, and sometimes doesnt, what can i do to ensure it will always click

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the desired item is not loaded on DOM yet, use 'WebDriver wait' to wait until dynamic content is loaded.

Comment: but i dont know how to do the wait for the variable that i created, because it has multiple types of elements

Comment: as you can see, it has xpath and a class name, or how can i implement the wait with name that i made 'desiredItem'

Comment: @ExoticLegend714 It's basically a function that takes xPath or any kind of identifier as parameter, and waits until that element is loaded. It's something like: wait.Until(identifier). I can not explain this in detail now. Just search for "python web driver wait" and you'll get the rest of it hopefully, how to import and stuff.

Comment: Ok but can you show an example of a webdriverwait?